# Not able to find pyspark in spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

I have downloaded the source from [Spark download link](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.4.0/spark-1.4.0.tgz) , and i have built it using

```
build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

but when i do `jar -tf spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar |grep pyspark`
It doesn't show any results.I am building it on CentOS  6.6. Am I creating the assembly jar wrong ?

I have looked at [AWS EMR Spark "No Module named pyspark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919632/aws-emr-spark-no-module-named-pyspark) and it looks like his assembly JAR shows a pyspark class.

 Apache Spark documentation is not completely clear on this.(or I maybe mistaken)

Please enlighten me on the following :

1. To run pyspark on yarn , does the assembly JAR need to contain the pyspark class ?
2. If yes, how can I add it to the assembly jar?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal -- the assembly jar does not have any pyspark classes.

Edit:

You can find the jars that pyspark uses by searching for the `java_import` function from `py4j`. It looks like those jars are:

```
# From java_gateway.py
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.SparkConf")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.api.java.*")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.api.python.*")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.*")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.sql.*")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.*")
java_import(gateway.jvm, "scala.Tuple2")

# From context.py:
java_import(gw.jvm, "org.apache.spark.streaming.*")
java_import(gw.jvm, "org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*")
java_import(gw.jvm, "org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.*")
```